# jnilib exist in a directory of MAC, and I specify and export this path in LD_LIBRARY_PATH and DY_LD_LIBRARY_PATH and export, but still errors found

Tags: macos, dlopen

I compile a jnilib in MAC with cc,

When I run the java application, but still get the errors below:

> dlopen(/Users/yz/Desktop/Home/code/test/framework/so/libtest.jnilib, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/libtest.dylib\n  Referenced from: /Users/yz/Desktop/Home/code/test/framework/so/libtest.jnilib\n  Reason: image not found
>
> Unfortunately, ths libtest.jnilib exists in /Users/yz/Desktop/Home/code/test/framework/so/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this problem with solution below:

Explaination:
The libtest.jnilib above referenced to another a.dylib, but this a.dylib did not exist in the dirs specified by LD_LIBRARY_PATH and DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, so when I call System.loadLibrary("test"), it failed.

it works for me that I copy a.dylib to one dir which in LD_LIBRARY_PATH or DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH.